# reex match multiple line - Golang

Tags: regex, go

why the following regex does not work on multiline,

https://play.golang.org/p/f0uOis_W4qY

```
func main() {
r := regexp.MustCompile(`image:\s*?"?{{.*}}\s*?"?`)
const s = `../cbur/templates/avamar_deployment.yaml:          image: "{{ .Values.global.registry }}/{{ .Values.image.avamar.name }}:{{ .Values.image.avamar.tag }}"
    ../cbur/templates/avamar_deployment.yaml:          image: "{{ .Values.global.registry1 }}/{{ .Values.image.avamar.name }}:{{ .Values.image.avamar.tag }}"`
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", r.FindStringSubmatch(s))
```

}

any hints please how to achieve this ? desired output :

image: "{{ .Values.global.registry }}/{{ .Values.image.avamar.name }}:{{ .Values.image.avamar.tag }}"

image: "{{ .Values.global.registry1 }}/{{ .Values.image.avamar.name }}:{{ .Values.image.avamar.tag }}"

Comment: Do you mean you want to get two matches?

Comment: yes correct, want to have all the result that match the pattern

Comment: Use [`FindAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString).

Comment: thanks, this solved my issue